# Make image fill screen without compromising second image on top placement

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place an a book (img2) on a bookshelf (img1), and the following code is positioning the book based on the window and not the position of the bookshelf. I was wondering if anyone knew how to make the book position based on the bookshelf. Right now the book is resizing properly but not positioning itself right.

```
<style>
        .bookcontainer {

        }
        .img1 {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 90%;  
            position: absolute;
            margin:auto;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
        }
        .img2 {
          position:absolute;
          right: 40%;
          top: 15%;
          width: 50%;
          max-width:50%;
        }
</style>

<div class="bookcontainer">
  <img class="img1" src="/assets/shelfbg.png">
  <img class="img2" src="/assets/book.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent container must have the css position set too, so let the bookshelf img define space and let the book be absolute this way:

```
.bookcontainer {
    position: relative;
}
.img1 {
    width: 100%;
}
.img2 {
    position:absolute;
    right: 40%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width:50%;
}
```

That way, using percents you can adjust the book position and size relative to its parent container.

Comment: That doesn't work because img2 gets sized based on x axis window size instead of img1's size. Suggested fix: on img1 replace `max-width: 100%;` to `width: 100%;`

Comment: It really depends on your other styles, but you have the clue now.